# Cant find dynamically created ids with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create Ids like the following:

```
var plant_counter = 0;

$('.plant-name').attr('id', 'plant-name-' + plant_counter);
```

After that i try to change the html code of this element:

```
    $('#nav-btn-test').click (function () {
    $('#plant-name-0').html('hello');
    console.log('clicked);
});
```

The html code does not change. Why?

Comment: With the posted code, you are missing a quote around 'clicked' this will throw and error. And i dont think you want to use .html rather .text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that is setting the IDs will not work because the variable *plant_counter* is not being updated (it will always be 0).

Use jQuery's .each method (see the documentation [HERE](https://api.jquery.com/each/)), something like this:

```
$('.plant-name').each(function( index ) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'plant-name-' + index);
});
```

*Aside*: In the click handle registration, you're missing a closing single quote (') at the end of the logging statement.

Here is a working example [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fvc3xfhq/)  for you to copy.

Answer (score 0):

In your posted code the 'clicked' is missing a quote. Also I think you want to use .text instead of .html

```
var plant_counter = 0;

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.plant-name').attr('id', 'plant-name-' + plant_counter);
    $('.btn').click (function () {
        $('#plant-name-0').text('hello');
        console.log('clicked');
    });
   console.log("ready");
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/floor_/5o3c3oqe/)  <-- click here for demo

Comment: still not working. error seems to lay before that. I .clone().replaceAll() this element. Maybe it has something to do with this step

Comment: If there are errors with code not posted, then you should post all your code. My demo works if you click on it.

Comment: This isn't updating the plant_counter variable, so it won't work for more than one plant.

Comment: @decates Its a proof of concept. I think the OP can figure out how to increment a counter. I gave a solution based on code provided. So that is why I didn't update the plant_counter.

Comment: If I check the html code via browser the ID is placed correct:<div class="text-center plant-name" id="plant-name-0"> testname </div> I can also change the html text of an div next to that element but this single one wont change.

Comment: "but this single one wont change" I don't know what you are referring to. Could you add all your code to a jsFiddle so I can see what you are talking about.